# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://websitename.herokuapp.com/js/bootstrap.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm running a node.js server on heroku using the express.js framework.

Here is what my server looks like:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

app.listen(port);
```

My index.html file has the following javascript links:

```
<script src="/js/chartview.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

My directory system looks like this:

```
server.js
/static
    -index.html
    -/js
        -bootstrap.js
        -bootstrap-select.js
        -chartview.js
    -/css
        -bootstrap.css
        -bootstrap-select.css
        -styles.css
```

Chrome displays my html page with the appropriate css styles but the console says:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   https://websitename.herokuapp.com/js/chartview.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   https://websitename.herokuapp.com/js/bootstrap.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   https://websitename.herokuapp.com/js/bootstrap-select.js
```

It loads properly when I change my index.html  tags to look like this:

```
<script src="chartview.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap-select.js"></script>
```

And I change my directory systems to look like this:

```
server.js
/static
    -index.html
    -bootstrap.js
    -bootstrap-select.js
    -chartview.js
    -/css
        -bootstrap.css
        -bootstrap-select.css
        -styles.css
```

This is not Ideal, as I would like to have a /js folder.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look closely at the urls, the /js is missing from `https://websitename.herokuapp.com/chartview.js` etc . . .

Comment: what comes up when you go to the url manually, still 404?

Comment: typing https://websitename.herokuapp.com/js/chartview.js in chrome displays "Cannot GET /js/chartview.js" in the browser.

Comment: Are the directory and file permissions all the same (css, js, and html)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the console error, `https://websitename.herokuapp.com/js/chartview.js`, the file is not being checked in static folder.

So, change your index.html to include scripts like this.

`<script src="js/chartview.js"></script>`  i.e remove `/` from beginning. as path is relative to index.html.

Follow same process for other three files.

Also, you mentioned that the CSS files are loaded correctly. Can you show how exactly are you including those css files? i.e the path for css.

Comment here, if that doesn't help.

Comment: I honestly thought that I had already tried that but I did it again and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try Placing your files in the public folder and use the path like this""

Answer (score -1):

Don't use "__dirname"
Only using

```
app.use(express.static('static'));
```

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem but thanks for the tip